# Split Uppercase words in Excel

Tags: regex, vba, excel, excel-formula

I would like to split all words in my cell by Uppercase, an example:

Original values:

```
MikeJones
RinaJonesJunior
MichealSamuelsLurth
```

Expected output:

```
Mike Jones
Rina Jones Junior
Micheal Samuels Lurth
```

Can this be done without using VBA?

Comment: I don't think that is possible without using VBA.

Comment: It's possible; it's just not very practical (see below).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Having acknowledged Excellll's remarkable formula, the most efficient code solution would be `RegExp` based. This avoids long loops.

[image]

```
Function SplitCaps(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "([a-z])([A-Z])"
    SplitCaps = .Replace(strIn, "$1 $2")
End With
End Function
```

Comment: I was hoping you'd come along with a RegEx solution!  It does seem like the way to go.

Comment: This is very handy for me but how would I adapt this to split the caps but add 2 spaces rather than 1 e.g Mike  Jones? TIA.

Comment: @d1ch0t0my use `SplitCaps = .Replace(strIn, "$1  $2")`

Comment: Nice answer, is there a way to include underscores and numbers to this function? ie replace the underscores with spaces, and split the numbers with spaces , similar to the caps.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a worksheet function solution.  It ain't pretty, but if you're totally averse to using VBA, then I think you're stuck with ugly options only.  For text in `A1`, paste the following into `B1` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the formula as an array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(IF(CODE(MID(D1,ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&LEN(D1))),1))<=90,IF(CODE(MID(D1,ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&LEN(D1))),1))>=65,IF(MID(D1,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(D1)-1)),1)<>" ",REPLACE(D1,ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&LEN(D1))),1," "&MID(D1,ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&LEN(D1))),1)),D1),D1),D1),MIN(IF(CODE(MID(D1,ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&LEN(D1))),1))<=90,IF(CODE(MID(D1,ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&LEN(D1))),1))>=65,IF(MID(D1,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(D1)-1)),1)<>" ",ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(D1)-1)),2000000),2000000),2000000))),D1)
```

I told you it was ugly!

And for all that effort, that will only split the first and second name. For more splits, fill the formula over to the right.  So for example, if you have a list of names in `A1:A10`, and you think the most words in any name is four, you could enter the formula in `B1` (as an array formula!), fill down to `B10`, then fill right to `E10`.  Your list of split names will be in `E1:E10`.

[image: sample use of formula]

If you're inclined to jump down the rabbit hole, here's a brief explanation of what the formula does:

1. Check each character to see if it is in the ASCII range for capital letters and not preceded by a space. The first character of the name is skipped.
2. An array equal in size to the length of the string (minus 1) is populated as follows: If a match is found, the string is stored with the matching character replaced by a space preceding itself. If no match is found, the original string is stored.
3. The first element from this array that corresponds to a match is returned. If no match is found, the original string is returned.

Comment: +1 for great use of native excel functions. Don't know how you did it!

Comment: @Remnant, I did a post the other day that covered a fair amount of these functions, used on a similar problem.  If you're interested it's at:  http://yoursumbuddy.com/solving-the-npr-sunday-puzzle-3/ . I was trying to put together an answer to this when I saw that Excellll had me beat by a mile :).

Comment: + 1 Nice One :-) Ugly? Well beauty lies in the eye of the beholder LOL +1 Doug ;)

Comment: Problem is, your formula will insert spaces in legit abbreviations like "KFC" which will become "K F C".

Comment: This also works as is (just paste in) in Google Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 3):

Since you say you would not like to use a VBA macro, but the problem requires VBA, I think a UDF will be a nice solution for you. This is a UDF (User defined Function) that you can use. Put this code in a general module of the same file that you have the data in.

```
Function splitbycaps(inputstr As String) As String

Dim i As Long
Dim temp As String

If inputstr = vbNullString Then
    splitbycaps = temp
    Exit Function
Else
    temp = inputstr
    For i = 1 To Len(temp)
        If Mid(temp, i, 1) = UCase(Mid(temp, i, 1)) Then
            If i <> 1 Then
                temp = Left(temp, i - 1) + " " + Right(temp, Len(temp) - i + 1)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    splitbycaps = temp

End If
End Function
```

You can now use the function directly in a cell. Suppose you have data in A1 -> "MikeJones"
And you want answer in cell A2. So in A2, you enter

```
=splitbycaps(A1)
```

And you will get your output. 
HTH.

Comment: UDF is definitely the way to go, but @brettdj 's regexp example below is prob more efficient. at least this one should start at char 2

Answer (score 1):

you have to do this with VBA.

```
Sub insertspaces()
Range("A1").Select
Do
    Row = ActiveCell.Row
    Column = ActiveCell.Column
    vlaue = ActiveCell.Value
    If vlaue = "" Then Exit Do
        Length = Len(vlaue)
        If Length > 1 Then
            For x = Length To 2 Step -1
            par = Mid(vlaue, x, 1)
            cod = Asc(par)
            If (cod > 64 And cod < 91) Or (cod > 191 And cod < 222) Then
            vlaue = Left(vlaue, x - 1) + " " + Mid(vlaue, x)
            End If
        Next
        ActiveCell.Value = vlaue
        End If
    Row = Row + 1
    Cells(Row, Column).Select
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work as a user defined function.

```
Function SplitOnCapital(str As String) As String
    Dim letter As Byte, result As String

    For letter = 2 To Len(str)
        If Asc(VBA.Mid$(str, letter, 1)) < 90 Then //65 to 90 are char codes for A to Z
            result = WorksheetFunction.Replace(str, letter, 0, " ")
            letter = letter + 1
        End If
    Next letter

    SplitOnCapital = result
End Function
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Sub caps_small()

strIn = InputBox("Enter a string:")

For i = 1 To Len(strIn)

    If Mid(strIn, i, 1) Like "[A-Z]" Then
        cap = Mid(strIn, i, 1)
        capstr = capstr & cap

    ElseIf Mid(strIn, i, 1) Like "[a-z]" Then
        sml = Mid(strIn, i, 1)
        smlstr = smlstr & sml
    End If
Next

MsgBox capstr

MsgBox smlstr


End Sub
```