# Excel function returns #Value

Tags: excel

I am using Excel and trying to use VBA to split some text that I have. I followed the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190269/split-uppercase-words-in-excel) post however all the cell returns is #VALUE!. I'm using Office 2016 OSX.

The function I have added is as follows:

```
Function SplitCaps(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "([a-z])([A-Z])"
    SplitCaps = .Replace(strIn, "$1 $2")
End With
End Function
```

I have made sure the module is named differently to the function.

1. As a test I have 1 entry in my sheet "MikeJones" in cell A1.
2. in cell B1 I have the formula "=SplitCaps(A1)"

..but the value is returned as #VALUE!. What idiotic thing am I missing here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inferior Excel for Mac is years behind Excel for Windows and does not support `vbscript.regexp`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995007/how-to-develop-an-excel-macro-that-contains-regular-expressions-so-it-will-work)

Comment: Ahh, thanks for cluing me in. I'll fire up Parallels :).