# Cleaning bad data in excel, splitting words by capital letters

Tags: regex, macos, vba, excel

I'm using excel 2011 on Mac OSX.  I have a data set with about 3000 entries.  In the fields that contain names, many of the names are not separated.  First and last names are separated by a space, but separate names are bunched together.

Here's what I have, (one cell):

> Grant MorrisonSholly Fisch
> Ben OliverCarlos Alberto Fernandez Urbano
> Ben OliverCarlos Alberto Fernandez Urbano
> Ben Oliver
> Ben Oliver

Here's what I want to accomplish, (one cell, comma separated with one space after comma):

> Grant Morrison, Sholly Fisch, Ben Oliver, Carlos Alberto, Fernandez Urbano, Ben Oliver, Carlos Alberto, Fernandez Urbano, Ben Oliver, Ben Oliver

I have found a few VBA scripts that will split words by capital letters, but the ones I've tried will add spaces where I don't need them like this one...

```
Function splitbycaps(inputstr As String) As String

Dim i As Long
Dim temp As String

If inputstr = vbNullString Then
    splitbycaps = temp
    Exit Function
Else
    temp = inputstr
    For i = 1 To Len(temp)
        If Mid(temp, i, 1) = UCase(Mid(temp, i, 1)) Then
            If i <> 1 Then
                temp = Left(temp, i - 1) + " " + Right(temp, Len(temp) - i + 1)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    splitbycaps = temp

End If
End Function
```

There was another one that I found here that used RegEx, (forgive me, I'm just learning all of this so I may sound a little dumb) but when I tried that one, it wouldn't work at all, and my research pointed me to a way to add references to the library that would add the necessary tools so I could use it.  Unfortunately, I cannot, for the life of me, find how to add a reference to the library on my mac version of excel...  I may be doing something wrong, but this is the answer that I could not get to work...

```
Function SplitCaps(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "([a-z])([A-Z])"
    SplitCaps = .Replace(strIn, "$1 $2")
End With
End Function
```

I am basically brand new at adding custom functions via VBA through excel, and there may even be a better way to do this, but it seems like every answer that I come to just doesn't quite get the data right.  Thanks for any answers!

Comment: That first function would work for you with a little bit of editing. Im guessing when you said its adding spaces in undesired locations had to do with names where the previous char is space, and with the <br> part. You can simply add another If statement or add on to the existing one to catch those characters and have it perform in the way you intend.

Comment: What Im getting at is, youre practically already there, just a little more and youve got it 

Comment: Do you ALWAYS have a combination of first and last names? What I am asking is if you always have a pair of strings, even without being formatted as the examples you are showing (sorry the caps but I do not know how to bold in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My function from [Split Uppercase words in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190269/split-uppercase-words-in-excel/10202057#10202057) needs udpdating for your additional string matching.

You would use this function in cell `B1` for text in `A1` as follows
[image]

One assumption your cleansing does make is people have only two names, so

> Ben OliverCarlos Alberto

is broken to

> Ben Oliver
>   Carlos Alberto

is that actually what should happen? (needs a  minor tweak if so)

*code*

```
Function SplitCaps(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "([a-z])([A-Z])"
    SplitCaps = Replace(.Replace(strIn, "$1, $2"), "<br>", ", ")
End With
End Function
```

Comment: I don't think the `vbscript.regexp` lib is available on MacOSX, otherwise this was the better, more flexible, solution.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos My bad - saw my solution from last time and missed the Mac OSX reference.

Comment: Thank you, guys.  Tried the function and it only returns #VALUE!  I'm assuming this is an OSX problem with the regexp, and if so, is there a workaround?  Some kind of patch or something that you know of??

Comment: @brettdj - I emailed the file to myself and took it to a windows machine.  The function worked great.  I gave up on the Mac workaround.  I'm sure it's out there, but whatevs.  Thank you!!